# Can Windows Mobile compatible ActiveX controls be created in .Net C# with Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, activex

I have searched and searched for a solid answer so now I'm just asking it...

Can ActiveX controls be developed/written in .Net C# with Visual Studio 2008 for use on Windows Mobile 6.5.X IE Browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The Compact Framework does not have EE Hosting support so native code cannot load managed code.  This means that you cannot create COM/ActiveX compliant assemblies with the .NET Compact framework as its impossible to export the required entry points.